# login failure due to faulty shell

Tags: login

I often run the most recent build of my login shell (zsh). Yesterday, the most recent build was defective, and it crashed immediately. Running it in a terminal was no huge problem since I had other open terminals running stable versions so I could correct the link to the defective shell.  However, I stupidly rebooted with the defective shell active in /etc/passwd, and on reaching the login prompt, login was impossible due to the defective shell.  I'm wondering if there is some way around that, i.e. some way of setting a fallback shell, or getting the login to prompt you for another shell in case the default is defective ... anything like that.  As it is, I rebooted to a backup install, and made the repair that way, but it's a bit clumsy.

Comment: If login as `root` is enabled, you could always do that on a virtual console, but many distros rely on `sudo` these days, so your only solution would be to boot in single user mode or use a repair bookable device.

Comment: I'm logging in as root as it is.  I can always log in as another user, using a different shell, but of course that user can't change anything belonging to root, so I'm stuck without booting to another install ... unless there is some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shell was totally defective and just exited with an error as soon as it was invoked, you could make a fake shell that was just a POSIX shell script that ran your shell and or the exit code with itself as a fallback.

```
#!/bin/sh

# this is usually some incredibly limited shell like dash
fallback_shell=/bin/sh
primary_shell="$(getent passwd `whoami` | cut -d: -f7)"

"$primary_shell" || "$fallback_shell"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you can log in as root. Some distributions disable logging in as root directly, but you can enable is simply by assigning a password to the root account. This is not insecure (just pick a password that's at least as strong as the one for your account). Of course don't use an experimental shell on the root account (you shouldn't be doing complex stuff on that account anyway).

For more safety, you can create an additional entry in the user database for the same user. You can have multiple entries in `/etc/passwd` with the same user ID (so it's the same user) but different user names (so they're distinguished at the login prompt), different home directories and different login shells. To create such an entry, edit `/etc/passwd` by running the command `vipw`, duplicate the entry for your account, and change the username and the login shell for the second entry. Then run `vipw -s` to change the password file (`/etc/shadow`); duplicate the entry for your account and change the username but leave the password alone.

For example, these are the first two lines of my `/etc/passwd` (`sash` is a statically-linked shell with some additional builtins, good for system repair):

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/not/bin/sh
sashroot:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sash
```

Comment: Gilles, the problem is that I run as root normally so root can't be my fallback. If I log in as a normal user then I haven't permissions to fix the root account.

Comment: This is actually a great answer @rayandrews -- you're basically just making a second "root" user named something else, with a different e.g. fallback shell.